# Value change notification property in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, notifications

How do I use the value change notification property in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

When a property is binded to UI element, and if the property value changes , if you want to reflect the changed value on the binded UI element, you have make sure the property containing class should implement INotifyPropertyChanged inteface.

Comment: i wants to change the variable value declare in code behind. What i'm going to do..?

Comment: take  num is static integer variable. if num value is changed automatically event will fire. how to do...?????????